# Google Scope Authorizations Loop Endlessly When Previewing or Publishing Apps with Cloud SQL Database

Tags: google-app-maker

My organization set up Cloud SQL as the default for Google App Maker about one month ago.  In the last week, we have been unable to preview or publish apps that use Cloud SQL data sources, including the sample applications which worked perfectly before.  The failure occurs during the authorization process.  When previewing or publishing an app, Google App Maker displays a dialog stating "Deploying this app requires authorization".  Next it prompts the user for their Google account and then requests approval for the necessary authorizations (e.g., "Manage the data in your Google SQL Service instances").  After approving the authorization, the prompts to authorize begin over with the dialog stating "Deploying this app requires authorization".

Observations:

- We have repeated this problem on multiple different computers, networks, and four different user accounts.
- In the SQL cloud console, our Cloud SQL instance shows new databases being created for each app along with new database-specific user accounts
- All of the databases appear as expected when I log directly into the Cloud SQL database using phpMyAdmin
- Other apps which don't use a Cloud SQL datasource work fine, including an app that uses a calculated data source which is hosted in the same Cloud SQL instance
- The only errors in the Stack driver logs for the Cloud SQL database showed "INFO" level communication errors with the database (aborted connection...Got an error reading communication packets)
- I'm unable to find Stack driver logs for the apps because I cannot preview or publish them (either option would provide a link to the Stack driver logs)
- There are now approximately 20 databases in our SQL instance (mostly associated with simple app tests) and we have only used 1 GB of 10 GB of space in our SQL instance
- I haven't seen any related problems on the Google Issue Tracker for Google App Maker

I'd appreciate any help or suggestions on what to check in order to resolve this issue.

Comment: This certainly seems a bug in the platform. If you are still experiencing this problem, I'd suggest you open a G Suite support ticket and request to speak with the API support team. https://gsuite.google.com/support/

Comment: I tend to agree.  I've submitted a bug report on https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/145345198.  Will have to follow up with our admin for gsuite support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted an issue to Google Issue Tracker and Google corrected the problem.  They also provided a workaround if this problem happens again.

Here is the response from the Google development team posted on Google Issue Tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/145345198

---

> It's great to hear your up and working again!  We are aware of this issue and are working through a longer term fix.  The specific bug appears to be related to some changes made in the Google Cloud session policy control that may have rolled out to your domain recently interacting with AppMaker in a way that was not expected.  We've spent time diagnosing the underlying issue and we beleive we know the root cause.  I suspect your domain admin did a version of the workaround below.
>
> Without getting too far into the details, the specific bug is that for a Deployer of an AppMaker application, if the Google Cloud Session policy is set with any expiration time, the returned token AppMaker sees is invalid, triggering a loop in AppMaker trying to generate a valid security token.  Historically, these session tokens never expired but recently there was  beta feature launch that allowed domain admins to set them to expire.  We strongly suspect your domain recently set this expiration policy explicitly and that's what is causing the bug.
>
> The good news is that these policies are overridable per Organizational Unit and we have tested that OUs which have the original classic Never Expire setting do, in fact, allow AppMaker to work.
>
> My suspicion is that your domain admin has reverted recent, local changes to your organizational policy under the admin.google.com console, specifically under Security > Google Cloud session control (Beta).
>
> If this happens again, here the workaround we would recommend.  Note you don't need to do this if you're currently up and working. You will need the help of someone with admin.gogole.com powers, specifically User and Organizational Unit powers at your organization. It is a slight increase in security risk but it restores some classic behavior that was standard until recently.
>
> The summary of the workaround is to override the Google Cloud session control expiration setting such that individuals who need access to AppMaker deployments can have it.  To mitigate systemic security risk, this is best done by creating a limited purpose Organizational Unit with just that setting different than the parent OU settings.
>
> The workaround is to:
>
> 1. Contact someone in your domain with Admin powers for your Google for Business license.
> 2. Have your admin proceed to https://admin.google.com.  The actions below need to be performed by a domain admin.
> 3. Under the Users section, identify the specific user account that needs the ability to deploy AppMaker Apps.
> 4. Identify the Organizational Unit of that Appmaker dev user and make a note of it.
> 5. Under the Organization Units settings, locate the Organization Unit you identified above.
> 6. Create a new Organization Unit underneath that user's current Organizational Unit with some descriptive identifying it as special w.r.t AppMaker. So for Developers, make something like DevelopersWhoAreAlsoAppMakerDevs.
> 7. Back under the Users tab, locate the user from step 3.  Move this user into the new Organizational Unit you've just created. This change can take a while to propagate.
>
> -Interlude- At this point, you've made a new Organizational Unit for just that individual and added them to it.  You can certainly add multiple people to that OU, especially if they're already in the same parent OU.  Use your discretion as to what amount of Organizational rework you wish to pursue.  You may not be using OUs at all or you may decide to just turn off this control for the whole domain. It's up to you.
>
> 8. Under admin.google.com's Security settings, locate the Google Cloud session control (beta) settings.
> 9. Under this panel, from the dropdown menu on the left, locate the Organization Unit you just created.
> 10. Be sure to select ONLY the OU you intend to change.
> 11. Change the "Google Cloud Console and Google Cloud SDK session control" from expiring to "Session Never Expires".
> 12. Save your changes.
>
> The account you selected in step 3 should now be able to deploy AppMaker apps.
>
> It appears this OU change is only necessary for the deployer of an AppMaker app, not an individual user.  Note also that if you have multiple AppMaker developers who all have different current OU settings, you may need to create multiple daughter OUs to avoid a sudden radical shift in OU settings for an individual account.